# Increase the maximum number of choices in filter_select() in crosstalk in R

Tags: r, crosstalk

I want to create a dropdown menu with the crosstalk package. My data has about 2000 choices. But with the filter_select() function only 1000 choices are possible. Can this limit be increased to 2000?

```
library(crosstalk)

df <- data.frame(g = seq(1, 2000))

df_shared <- SharedData$new(df)

crosstalk::filter_select(id = "test", label = "test", sharedData = df_shared, group = ~g, multiple = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is possible to successfully type values past 1000. You can see some of those options populate for example when you type 100. There appears to be a limit in the implementation of crosstalk::filter_select() that prevents the full list from showing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Good to know that manual input is also possible. Nevertheless, it would be nice to see the complete list.